Are there infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p +2$ has at most two distinct prime factors?
using lower bound sieve, one can show that there are infinitely many prime $p$ such that $p+2$ has at most four distinct prime factors [Theorem 10.2.1, 1].
Has there been any improvement of the above result to at most two distinct prime factors?
[1] Cojocaru, A. C., & Murty, M. R. (2006). An introduction to sieve methods and their applications (No. 66). Cambridge University Press.

As Daniel says in his answer, this is exactly the content of Chen's Theorem.

I don't have access to the paper, but according to Wikipedia, Theorem II in Chen, J.R. (1973). "On the representation of a larger even integer as the sum of a prime and the product of at most two primes". Sci. Sinica. proves exactly this. See also Chen prime on Wikipedia.

Thanks for the suggestion! Chen's theorem proves that there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p+h$ is a product of at most two primes, h being any even integer. Do you happen to know whether it's possible to prove something similar for $h$ odd?

@Alexis it should be possible (and may be known) to get at most 3 primes in that case.

@WillSawin Thanks! Is there any reference for this or reason why it should be possible?

@Alexis Just general heuristics about how sieve methods work suggest that counting $p$ such that $ap+b$ has at most $n$ prime factors should have the same difficulty for fixed $n$ independent of $a,b$, as long as there is no obvious prime factor that $ap+b$ has to have. For $h$ odd $p+h$ has to have the factor $2$ but $p/2+h/2$ has no obvious factors and thus counting $p$ such that $p/2+h/2$ has at most $2$ prime factors should have the same difficulty  as counting $p$ such that $p+2$ has at most $2$ prime factors.
